# cannot git clone my project into my raspberrypi - git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). Could not read from remote repository

Tags: ssh, git

I am using a brand new raspberry pi.

I want to clone my project from my github account on my raspberrypi directory `/var/www/`.

So, as I am in `/var/www/`, I run

```
sudo git clone git@github.com:MY_USER/MY_PROJECT_REPO.git
```

but I get

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**Note:** I have to use sudo since `/var/www/` owner is `root`.

I have read [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12940681/7658051) that I have to do the key exchange between my machine and my github account.

So I go to directory `~` and run

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "MY_ADDRESS@DOMINION.com"
```

let it generate the file `~/.ssh/ed25519.pub` and give a password.

then I run

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

copy the output , that is something like

```
`ssh-ed25519 ... MY_ADDRESS@DOMINION.com`
```

then go to https://github.com/settings/keys , click on the button "new SSH key",

and paste the text into the form, then save.

then I run

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

type the password I inserted before.

Then in `/var/www/` I run again

```
sudo git clone git@github.com:MY_USER/MY_PROJECT_REPO.git
```

but I still get the same error.

I have checked that running

```
git clone git@github.com:MY_USER/MY_PROJECT_REPO.git
```

in home directory (`~`) works, so the problem is only related to location `/var/www/`.

For the moment, I have solved by running

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/MY_USER/MY_PROJECT_REPO.git
```

instead of

```
sudo git clone git@github.com:MY_USER/MY_PROJECT_REPO.git
```

but I still don't understand why the error happens.

Comment: To debug an ssh connection in git, first `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vv"`.